# How to add and item to an array inside an object which is inside an array without chaning the initial array? Pure Function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
const list = [{
  items: [
    "2",
    "3",
  ],
}, {
  items: [
    "1",
  ],
}, ];
const selectedList = 0;

const newList = [...list];
newList[selectedList].items = [...list[selectedList].items, "4"];

console.log(list); // X [ { items: [ '2', '3', '4' ] }, { items: [ '1' ] } ] // <-- why does it have 4 inside?
console.log(newList); // ✓ [ { items: [ '2', '3', '4' ] }, { items: [ '1' ] } ]
```

I expect list to be `[ { items: [ '2', '3' ] }, { items: [ '1' ] } ]` and newList `[ { items: [ '2', '3', '4' ] }, { items: [ '1' ] } ]`. Why does list have the '4' as well? I'm spreading the list and not chaning the items of the original list?

Comment: `[...list]` is a shallow copy, one level deep. Very related: [what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: because spread does shallow copy the inside arrays still have the same reference

Comment: Yes, I know but beside that. The problem was that the object it self was still a reference

Comment: That *is* what is meant with shallow copy. It is not "besides that". That *is* the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the items property of `newList[selectedList]`, you can create a whole new object.  Since it's a new object, it won't have an effect on `list[selectedList]`.

```
newList[selectedList] = {items: [...list[selectedList].items, "4"]};
```

```js
const list = [{
  items: [
    "2",
    "3",
  ],
}, {
  items: [
    "1",
  ],
}, ];
const selectedList = 0;

const newList = [...list];
newList[selectedList] = {items: [...list[selectedList].items, "4"]};

console.log(list); // X [ { items: [ '2', '3', '4' ] }, { items: [ '1' ] } ] // <-- why does it have 4 inside?
console.log(newList); // ✓ [ { items: [ '2', '3', '4' ] }, { items: [ '1' ] } ]
```